# How to tint the video, but still display the MediaController progress bar?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

In my application I am using VideoView to play a video. Through this forum I have learnt to show the progress bar (MediaController) persistently (without hiding).

My requirement is to tint the video on some action (lets say pause on MediaController), but still be able to use the MediaController. i.e., once the video is tinted, I could move the progress-bar on MediaController and could also play the video again (after un-tinting it).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?